# jqGrid does not call blockUI without setTimeout when ajax fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I'm using jqGrid ***4.54*** in my project and I want to place a message blocking the UI when there's a server error.

I know that blockUI ***2.66.0*** does not work with synchronous ajax so I'm using the jqGrid like this:

```
$.extend($.jgrid.ajaxOptions, { async: true });
$.extend($.jgrid.defaults, {
    mtype: "POST",
    altRows: true,
    datatype: "json",
    loadonce: true,
    height: "auto",
    width: 1100,
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
    viewrecords: true,
    pager: "#paginacao",
    sortorder: "asc",
    shrinkToFit: false,
    headertitles: true,
    loadui: "disable",
    rownumbers: true,
    emptyrecords: "<strong>Não houve resultado para o seu filtro.<strong>",
    autoencode: true,
    caption: "Resultados encontrados",
    deselectAfterSort: true,
    gridview: true,
    idPrefix: "id",
    rowTotal: 4000,
    sortable: true,
    toppager: true,
    loadError: function(xhr, status, error) {
        $.blockUI({
            message: '<p style=\"font-weight: bolder; color: white;\">Erro ao tentar gerar relat&oacute;rio, por favor, tente novamente.<br /><br /><a onclick=\"$.unblockUI();\">Fechar</a></p>',
            timeout: 5000,
            onOverlayClick: $.unblockUI
        });
    },
    jsonReader: {
        root: "rows",
        page: "page",
        total: "total",
        records: "records",
        repeatitems: true,
        id: 0,
        cell: ""
    }
});
```

But this way the plugin does not work at all. When I get the blockUI and wrap it in a window.setTimeout does work like below:

```
loadError: function(xhr, status, error) {
    window.setTimeout("$.blockUI({ message: '<p style=\"font-weight: bolder; color: white;\">Erro ao tentar gerar relat&oacute;rio, por favor, tente novamente.<br /><br /><a onclick=\"$.unblockUI();\">Fechar</a></p>', timeout: 5000, onOverlayClick: $.unblockUI});", 10);
}
```

Does anyone know how to make this works without window.setTimeout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had our AJAX request default settings conflicting with the *jqGrid* plugin. Since we've developed a *jQuery* plugin, we decided to set these settings into an `$.ajax` object inside a method as shown below.

```
$.fn.carregaConteudoViaAjax = function(url, dados, idElemento) {
    if (typeof idElemento === "undefined") {
        idElemento = "#" + this.attr("id");
    }

    $.ajax({
        url : url,
        data : dados,
        success : function(result, statusRequestAjax, xhr) { $(idElemento).html(result.mensagem); },
        type: "POST",
        dataType : "json",
        cache : false,
        error : function(xhr, statusRequestAjax, error) { $("#msgErros").html(error); },
        beforeSend: function() { $.blockUI(); },
        complete : function() { $.unblockUI(); }
    });

    return this;
};
```

And then we call the method like this: `$("#idElemento").carregaConteudoViaAjax(url, objetoJS);`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I also face the same earlier.  As I know javascript code is asynchronous.  When your ajax call fired, by default ajax also asynchronous.

Basically what is happening is your javascript code is continue to run before ajax call complete and get the results.  So you have to make your use grid load function to be **synchronous**.

Try some thing like this: `$.extend($.jgrid.ajaxOptions, { async: false });`
(Goal is to make your grid load ajax should be synchronous.)

Let me know if it works.

Comment: As I said, blockUI unfortunatelly does not work with synchronous ajax, if I use this way blockUI feature stops working, plus, I did test your suggestion and still doesn't work.

Comment: In place of setTimeout, call an `alert` before calling blockUI and see if it is working.  This is just to debug.

Comment: I added an alert and a console.log and they both work with the exiting window.setTimeout call. Since jgGrid is basically ajax requests I think this is the problem with the blockUI plugin that only works with asynchronous ajax requests.